# Is it possible to migrate struts/spring based application to GWT?

Tags: java, design, architecture, java-ee, gwt

I am using the combination of spring, spring-security, struts and iBatis in my application. Now I am looking to migrate the struts UI to GWT.

The new combination must be spring, spring-security, GWT and iBatis.

I applied a layered approach to develop my application. In Controller/UI layer i am using Struts. I want to replace struts and use GWT in Controller/UI layer.

Is is possible to use GWT without affecting another layers DAO/BL/SL?

Comment: Why GWT as opposed to say Spring MVC?  I assume because you don't want to have to deal with Javascript etc?

Comment: Correct .. I want to handle AJAX and JavaScript related stuff in more frequent way. Also GWT provides rich client look and feel tools are very nice to work on.

Comment: Some other technologies that you may consider for the presentation layer would be JSF or Wicket, both can also integrate well into Spring.  I warn though that there are always little quirks and oddities in any of these frameworks that will force you to write custom javascript from time to time.

Comment: The previous answers give good advice. I'd just like to add that there is a Vaadin add-on ([JSP Integration](https://vaadin.com/directory#!addon/jsp-integration)) that might help during the migration process, depending on your actual migration strategy and whether your current Struts implementation uses JSP as a view technology.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about conceptual software design.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is: Yes, you can.

The problem is how to do it, as you will probably need a rewrite of your presentation layer and I don't think there is any tool that can help you easy up the migration.

Comment: Do i need to edit, spring application context and spring security settings also?

Comment: Well, I haven't seen your code, but I you'll probably have to adapt them too. It depends on how tied they are to the presentation layer and how you finally decide to do the migration.

Answer (score 2):

Well, yes, sure you can. Just make sure that the classes used in your frameworks are on the GWT white list. What that means in practice is:

- Decide on the version of GWT you'll use in your project. If no constrains exist, use the latest.
- Decide the versions of the other frameworks as well.
- Decide which of the classes from those frameworks will be used in the CLIENT side code of your GWT project

Finally, if you arrive in a situation where certiain classes that come from your framework(s) will not be directly usable in GWT client code, there's multiple solutions:

- check out if there's not already a "bridge" library/framework that deals with this issue (like Gilead for Hibernate)
- if you have to do it by hand, explore the options (by maybe doing a small proof of concept): either implement a custom serialization policy, or make a DTO layer, etc.